# Set always copy to local property for a .net application

Tags: c#, vb.net, network-programming, windows-server-2012

I am using a portable chat application (built in vb,net) via LAN which is placed in local server(Windows server 2012) computer say computer1. I have another Windows server(Windows server 2012) PC in which around 10 people are working. Say that pc as computer2. While working in computer2 we used to access chat application from computer1.

Some time I will update the some features of chat application and replace that in computer1 without any error. Now in order to make latest version of application available to the users of computer2, all the working users in computer2 has to close and then open the chat application. This is the procedure which need to be done in order to open the latest version of app,

```
userA and userB are using chat application,
userA, userb both closes the application
userA, userb opens the app
```

Here is my problem,

```
userA and userB are using chat application,
I will update the app in computer1
userA closes the application but userB still kept that app open.
userA opens the app, here userA will get old version instead of new version which is available in computer1.
```

Why this is happening ? Where windows store the cache ?

Is it possible to set a property like "Always copy application to local when run from network" in .net ?

I know I can follow method1 as solution, but it is very difficult to know that all the users are closed the app so that I can inform again to open it.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you thought about [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t71a733d.aspx) ?